# CoreML2 keeps telling me everything is the same thing

Tags: swift, coreml

I am trying to start small and have trained my model with 2 items. It recognises both just fine but when I show it something other than the 2 items it knows, it keeps telling me that is is always the same item. For example, I have an apple and banana. If I show it the apple, it correctly gives me apple, if I show it a banana it correctly returns banana. But if I show it a dog, it tells me it is an apple. If I show it a helicopter it tells me it is an apple. I even tried an if statement to say that if it isn't an apple or a banana then just return that it can't be recognised, but that never comes because everything besides the banana is always an apple?!

**EDIT**
My question was down voted perhaps because of a misunderstanding. I am not asking why it doesn't recognise a dog when I have only trained an apple and banana, I am asking why it doesn't tell me that the image is unrecognised when I show it a dog instead of telling me it's an apple. Obviously if I have only trained it with 2 items it is only going to recognise 2 items.

Here is the code that returns the classifications

```
func processClassifications(for request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let results = request.results else {
            self.classificationLabel.text = "Unable to classify image"
            return
        }

        let classifications = results as! [VNClassificationObservation]

        if classifications.isEmpty {
            self.classificationLabel.text = "Nothing recognized"
        } else {
            //Display top classifications ranked by confidence in the UI
            let topClassifications = classifications.prefix(1)
            let descriptions = topClassifications.map { classification in
                return String(format: " (%.2f) %@", classification.confidence, classification.identifier)

            }


            self.classificationLabel.text = descriptions.joined(separator: "\n")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: create one more item called Unknowned

Comment: That's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have model trained with 2 items only (in your case Apple and Banana) you can't expect that your ML model recognize something else than these 2 items.
Code that you wrote always returns item which will have the biggest confidence.

---

Anyway, if you have more items, you can do something like: if no item matches with testing image for at least x%, do this

```
guard let topResult = classifications.first else { return }

if topResult.confidence > 0.75 {
    print(topResult.identifier)
} else {
    print("Match is less than 75%")
}
```

Comment: I would have thought though if you show it something that looks nothing like those 2 items it would not recognise it instead of telling you it is always one of the two things? I would rather have a not recognised message than everything being an apple

Comment: I am not expecitng it to give me the correct names for something I haven't trained, but I am not expecting it to tell me everything is an apple but rather that it doesn't recognise something that isn't an apple or a banana

Comment: thanks for that. It would have been perfect if the unknown images would score that low. I checked the scores and for a picture of a waterfall it seems to know with 100% certainty that it is an apple. So, that code of yours never fires.

Comment: @user8463989 If you print topResult.confidence right above if statement what is printed?

Comment: Well, a picture of a waterfall gives me 0.99999994 assurance that it's an apple. I tried changing the condition to == 1.00 instead of > 0.75 which works a bit better but it still gets things wrong like telling me that a field of flowers is 1.0 (100%) sure it's an apple

Comment: I don't think the model is necessarily trained bad as it recognises the two items I trained it on just fine. As this was only a test for now, I used about 30 images for training and between 5-10 for testing per item which surely be enough for something like an apple and banana

Answer (score 0):

In a model that is a classifier, you always get just as many `VNClassificationObservation` objects as there are classes. No more, no less. The array is only empty if there was a problem running the model.